# WSO2 ESB Analytics - Message Flow Not Displayed

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I've configured WSO2 ESB Analytics and data seems to be posting to analytics server. But once clicked on Success or Failed records the relevant message flow data isnt displayed. I've configured data to be stored on oracle database. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Did you check whether data has been persisted in the event tables ?
You can use Data Explorer of DAS Management Console for that 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Data+Explorer

Comment: Yes Kanaka, I checked Manage -> Interactive Analytics -> Data Explorer in DAS management console. Then selected a table name and filtered for a closer date time range. Found data written in several tables, is there a specific table I should check?

Comment: Can you try executing the batch scripts as mentioned in the sept 4 of https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Scheduling+Batch+Analytics+Scripts. and then check on the console.

Comment: Hi suho, I couldnt understand what you had mentioned, what script should I execute? and what result should I expect? There is a script that is there by default when logged to ESB Analytics, is that the script that I should execute?

Comment: Yes as Suho has suggested execute the default spark script included in the analytics pack. Usually what happens is data is persisted in the minute tables and aggregation will be done by spark script to load hour, day and month tables.